# GETDATE scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm retrieving a must declare scalar variable error for @StartFixtureDay but not sure what I need to do or see the problem with my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Date_Insert]

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

DECLARE @StartFixtureDay DATE
SET @StartFixtureDay = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

    ;WITH League_Dates AS (
...
 SELECT rn,
           week_number,
           DATEADD(day, week_number - 1, @StartFixtureDay) AS WeekNumber,
...
```

... The exec below is on a separate page

```
EXEC [dbo].[Date_Insert] @StartFixtureDay
```

Comment: Post full code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: So, *why* do you think you need to have `@StartFixtureDay` in the line `EXEC [dbo].[Date_Insert] @StartFixtureDay`? Have you put it there for a specific reason?

Comment: What is the idea of mentioning `@StartFixtureDay` in exec proc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare @StartFixtureDay as parameter on the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Date_Insert] (@StartFixtureDay date)
AS
...
```

Comment: And remove the DECLARE in the SP.

Comment: @RhysJones: Yes, of course. I guess setting `@StartFixtureDay` in the sp doesn't make sense. Maybe only if it's null?

Comment: Why have you come to this conclusion? The procedure they are calling is not the same one as the code.

Comment: @MartinSmith It looks like he's passing @StartFixtureDay as a parameter in `EXEC [dbo].[Fixture_Insert] @StartFixtureDay`but he's setting it also in the sp

Comment: They are different procedures. `Fixture_insert` vs `Date_Insert`.

Comment: @MartinSmith: you are right! Then I honestly don't know

Comment: @vercelli Don't worry about the name of the procedure, that was a typo when I typed it in a question, both procedures are actually Date_Insert and already set to that in the script

Comment: @DazzleVision: Ok. So it's my answer what you are looking for? Do you want to pass `@StartFixtureDay` as a parameter? We are not sure

Comment: @vercelli I actually get the same error when i set it as a parameter

Comment: @DazzleVision: please post the new stored procedure

Comment: @DazzleVision: you also have to declare the variable before calling the sp: `DECLARE @StartFixture DATE
SET @StartFixture = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
EXEC [dbo].[Date_Insert] @StartFixture`

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is not defined as having a parameter yet you are passing one.

You need to put the parameter into the procedure definition before you can pass it

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `@StartFixtureDay` INside of your stored procedure.
When you call `EXEC` you are OUTside of your procedure. 
And this OUTside code does'nt know about INside variables.
declare your variable before `EXEC` and declare parameters in your procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Date_Insert] (@ParamName DATE)
AS
    DECLARE @StartFixtureDay DATE
    SET @StartFixtureDay = @ParamName
...
```

...

```
DECLARE @OutsideVriable DATE
SET @OutsideVriable = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
EXEC [dbo].[Date_Insert] @OutsideVariable
```

Answer (score 0):

As you above all suggest based on your execution procedure, your datatime parameter need to define.

Also you are written wrong, please correct as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Date_Insert]

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

DECLARE @StartFixtureDay DATE
SET @StartFixtureDay = ( Select CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))  --direct cast not work, need to select keyword
```